# mkdir: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: script, powershell, mkdir

Estoy haciendo uso del siguiente script

[GitHub: Script de instalación desatendida](https://github.com/brookspeppin/Blogs/blob/main/DIY%20Zero-Touch%20Provisioning%20Process%20for%20Dell%20Systems/Apply-Image.ps1)

Durante la ejecución está ocurriendo el siguiente error:

```
mkdir : The given path's format is not supported.
At D:\Apply-Image.ps1:49 char:9
+         mkdir "$usb\Dell\"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

No logro identificar el origen del conflicto en el código, aprecio cualquier aporte.

Comment: Hola. Ahí te está diciendo que el carácter `:` no está soportado en una ruta a archivo. Te indica la línea 49 del script, que hace `mkdir "$usb\Dell\"` tal y como lo dice el mensaje de error. Hazle debug al contenido de `$usb`, entonces...

Answer (score 0):

Hola remueve los dos puntos ":" de la línea 44
En vez de:

```
$usb = (get-volume | Where FileSystemLabel -eq "DATA").DriveLetter + ":"
```

Prueba esto:

```
$usb = (get-volume | Where FileSystemLabel -eq "DATA").DriveLetter
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que no hay un disco con label DATA.  En ese caso el valor de $usb será ':'.  Y mkdir produce el error que reportas.

```
PS> $usb = ':'
PS> mkdir $usb\Dell\
>> TerminatingError(New-Item): "The given path's format is not supported."
>> TerminatingError(New-Item): "The given path's format is not supported."
The given path's format is not supported.
mkdir : The given path's format is not supported.
At line:1 char:1
+ mkdir $usb\Dell\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```